# Need File or URL, referencing a folder (NOT FILE) from raw or assets

Tags: java, android

I have once again had trouble using JWI Wordnet in Android. The only way to access it, is to create a URL or File pointing to the directory where the files it needs are located. http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/index.html I have downloaded the files I need, and added the jar into my project. My error is when I try to create the Dictionary object used to access wordnet. I don't point to a valid directory. Which makes sense, but I just don't know how to do so pointing the correct way. Basically, the folder name is "dict", I can place it into either raw or Assets (Although I read something about files in assets needing to be < 1 mb, the files inside the folder are greater than 1 mb) I need to create either a File or URL that points to said folder. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You should of course know full path to the dict folder to begin with. You can put files in assets at design time. Then at run time copy once your files from assets to that dict folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you cannot create a file from raw or assets directly, as they are not stored as files, but you can copy/unpack them somewhere else, and make a File object using the copy. [Android: how do I create File object from asset file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402690/android-how-do-i-create-file-object-from-asset-file)